# Using backticks in a knitr document

Tags: r, knitr

I have a simple knitr document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
`+`
@
\end{document}
```

which when compiled results in the error:

```
Error in parse(text=x, srcfile=src)
```

I was expecting the compiled document to show

```
R> `+`
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("+")
```

---

```
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: Wrapping it in `print` seems to work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `formatR`, which is used to tidy up your code before displaying and evaluating it. Your backticks get removed, leaving a bare `+`, which of course won't evaluate by itself:

```
tidy.source(text="`+`")
# +
```

You can do as joran said and wrap it in `print`, or you can set `tidy=FALSE`:

```
<<tidy=FALSE>>=
`+`
@
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been thinking of making `tidy=FALSE` the default these days, and this is further evidence that I should do it.

Comment: And I have eventually done it. In knitr 1.6 (not released yet), `tidy=FALSE` by default.